# Recreate XML from a string

Tags: python, xml

I have a XML string (simplified) that looks like this:

```
string_containing_xml = 'This string comes ok <ph id="1" ax:element-id="0">&lt;meta-ref&quot; type=&quot;dynamic&quot; name=&quot;Firmenname]&lt;/meta-ref&gt;</ph> this one is not coming'
        
xml_object_in_string = '<target xmlns:ax="AcrossXliff">{}</target>'.format(
                string_containing_xml.replace("&nbsp;", "&amp;nbsp;")
            )


final_xml = ET.fromstring(
            xml_object_in_string
        )
```

The final_xml contains only "This string comes ok". The <ph tag and the last string is skipped

How can I recreate that XML so it takes all into the account, and not only the first part of the text?

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have formatted the code. Basically, this code demonstrates the issue.

Comment: what is the expected xml doc?

Comment: You have not shown us any actual result (such as the output from `print(ET.tostring(final_xml))`). We cannot tell if anything is wrong based on a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
ET.tostring(final_xml).decode('utf-8')
```

Output:

```xml
'<target xmlns:ns0="AcrossXliff">This string comes ok <ph id="1" ns0:element-id="0">&lt;meta-ref" type="dynamic" name="Firmenname]&lt;/meta-ref&gt;</ph> this one is not coming</target>'
```